# process crash handler in Frida

Tags: frida

I'm trying to debug a crash in some process in iOS
frida-trace allows me to add handlers to specific functions, but I'd like to install a handler that prints the stack trace when the process crashes. How can I do it?

Comment: Usually iOS already generates a crash report with the stack if an app crashes. You can get the crash reports e.g. via `idevicecrashreport` (from libimobiledevice tools).

Comment: Do you have any suggestions for ways to read ips files? I'm tracking a crash in a private framework so I don't have .dysm files.

Comment: Try to get at least the assembler code using e.g. Ghidra, IDAPro or a similar reverse engineering too that works with ARM64 code. Hopefully by the crash report you should get at least class and method name where the error occurs. Then check the code of this method. reading assembler code is not easy but for a framework without code this is the only option.

Comment: Thanks, turns out my crash is JetsamEvent, so no code :) I'll see what I can do